# How to cast a list of concrete classes which implement an interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have an interface IAnimal and two classes(Dog, Cat), which both implement the interface.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Also, I have an AnimalsManager class as shown in the code below.

```
public class AnimalsManager
{
    private readonly List<Dog> _dogs = new List<Dog>();
    private readonly List<Cat> _cats = new List<Cat>();

    public void SetTargetAnimalsAge(bool isDog, int age)
    {
        if (isDog)
        {
            setAnimalsAge(_dogs, age);
        }
        else
        {
            setAnimalsAge(_cats, age);
        }
    }

    private static void setAnimalsAge<T>(IEnumerable<T> animals, int age) where T : class, IAnimal
    {
        foreach (var animal in animals)
        {
            animal.Age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

In the method SetTargetAnimalsAge, setAnimalsAge is used twice depending on the value of isDog argument. I'd like to unite these 2 usages into 1, but the following codes do not compile.

```
// Do not compile.
// var animals = isDog ? _dogs : _cats;
// var animals = isDog ? _dogs as List<IAnimal> : _cats as List<IAnimal>;

setAnimalsAge(animals, age);
```

How is it possible to handle one of the lists of Dogs and Cats as a list of IAnimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have it as `IList<T>` because `IList<T>` is not covariant but `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant. You can cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` and that should work.

For example, following code should work:

```
public void SetTargetAnimalsAge(bool isDog, int age)
{   
     var animals = isDog ? (IEnumerable<IAnimal>)_dogs : _cats;
     setAnimalsAge(animals, age);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `isDog ? _dogs : _cats as List<IAnimal>` was impossible, but `isDog ? _dogs : _cats as IList<IAnimal>`, `isDog ? _dogs : _cats as ICollection<IAnimal>`, `isDog ? _dogs : _cats as IEnumerable<IAnimal>` were all possible!!

Answer (score 3):

Please dont make 2 separate lists, one for dog & one for cat. `AnimalsManager` should know only about `IAnimal`. 
Stick to Interfaces & thus  [Dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

```
public class AnimalsManager
    {
        private readonly List<IAnimal> _animals = new List<IAnimal>();

        public void SetTargetAnimalsAge(int age)
        {
            setAnimalsAge(_animals, age);
        }

        private static void setAnimalsAge<T>(IEnumerable<T> animals, int age) where T : class, IAnimal
        {
            foreach (var animal in animals)
            {
                animal.Age = age;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And you can send a type argument to `SetTargetAnimalAge` if you only want to set the age of a certain type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only recently did I get to know Dependency inversion. I need to learn more.

Comment: @SimpleVar, yes, as long as `AnimalsManager` is only dealing with `IAnimal` is fine. But if `AnimalsManager` is made aware about extensions of `IAnimal` or if there is a `switch` depending upon the type of `IAnimal, then its a sign to check the design.

Comment: @user4134476, its one of the SOLID principals, you can read more here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)